# Array with unique values: indexOf vs new Set

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assuming we have an array with repeated items like so:

```
var items = ['a', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'd','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'd'];
```

What would be the fastest way to have a new array with the values, given that you **must** loop through the items (might make no sense, but that's the scenario).

Option 1:

```
var list = [];
items.forEach(function(item) {
    if(list.indexOf(item) == -1)
      list.push(item);
});
```

Option 2:

```
var list = [];
items.forEach(function(item) {
    list.push(item);
});

list = Array.from(new Set(list));
```

Now I have done some testing with console.time and it shows that the option 2 is 5 times faster that the option 1. But I am not sure how trustable this console.time is. 
Any insight? Is the `indexOf` what's making the option 1 slower?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q9opqvsm/

Edit: Another question: if option 2 is faster, should I change my code from option 1 => option 2. If not, why?

Comment: In your second example, why would you bother iterating through `items` and pushing them all into `list`? Why not just `list = Array.from(new Set(items));`?

Comment: indexOf, I believe, is going to look through the entire array, so you're doing extra work. Set is using a hash to determine if an element exists already so lookup is O(1). Also, you don't need to loop through the array, just use Array.from(new Set(items))

Comment: @Matt Burland That's the scenario. Might make no sense, this is a simplified version of something bigger.

Comment: _"Is the indexOf what's making the option 1 slower?"_ - yes. `indexOf` is `O(n)` meaning you have a loop inside your loop giving you overall `O(n2)`. In option 2 looking up a value in a set is `O(1)` and `Array.from` is `O(n)`, so you are `O(n)` overall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Is the indexOf what's making the option 1 slower?"

Yes. indexOf is O(n) meaning you have a loop inside your loop giving you overall O(n2). `indexOf` is equivalent of doing something like this:

```
function indexOf(item, array) {
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === item) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Which you can see has to, *in the worse case* (the item isn't already in the array) iterate the whole array. There's no way around it. If you are searching the array for a value you have to look at every item until you either find it, or run out of items.

In option 2 looking up a value in a set is O(1) and Array.from is O(n), so you are O(n) overall.

Making a set is somewhat equivalent to doing something like this (note this doesn't actually produce a set, but an object, so it's not exactly the same):

```
function makeSet(array) {
    var set = {};
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (set[array[i]] === undefined) {   // indexing `set` is O(1)
            set[array[i]] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

So it's `O(n)` overall. And creating an array from that is just a case of iterating the set and loading it into an array, which is also `O(n)`. So it's `O(n)` overall.

> Another question: if option 1 is faster, should I change my code from option 1 => option 2. If not, why?

Option 1 isn't faster, but if we pretend it is then the answer is that it depends. Option 1 certainly won't scale as well as option 2, but that doesn't mean option 1 might not be faster for small enough arrays (although I doubt it). Either way, this is premature optimization. If your code is running slow, and you profile your code and identify *this* part as the bottleneck, then you should worry about it.

Edit:

> Small typo, I meant if option 2 is faster. There are no bottlenecks,

So the same arguments about premature optimization still apply. But personally, I'd probably change it. It seems fairly low impact and if anything it might, arguably, have a clearer intent with option 2.

Although - do consider browser support for `Set`. It's relatively new and not supported by older browsers. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Small typo, I meant if option 2 is faster. There are no bottlenecks, was just some of those things that hit you out of the blue.

Comment: You have to point out also a little thing more. There are several algorithms for searching. For example if your list is ordered, you can perform a binary search, which will decrease your computational cost to O(logn). 
Of course if you need to manipulate the list multiple times adding/removing values, you have to keep it ordered in order to make binary search works.
Usually it depends on the frequency you do operations. If you perform a lot of researches and just some sporadic insertion/removal, you can keep the list ordered ("paying" more for these operations) but perform a better research.

Comment: @yBrodsky: If it was me, and this is new code that's being written (so there probably doesn't exist other code that relies on it yet), I'd change it. I think you could argue that the intent of option 2 is maybe actually clearer than in option 1. Of course, YMMV.

Comment: Yes. In my case, the amount of times that indexOf is being run is quite high. And since it's part of a larger process might be worth changing it.